# Asigning CSS property to variable in JavaScript [Polymer]

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I have simple question about asigning values of CSS properties to some variables is JavaScript in Polymer app.

Assume I have one `div` with `width:200px;`. In some JavaScript function i want to change width to `200px+10px`.

**I know i can apply this in JS in this way `div.style.top = '210px';`, but this is not what I need!**

I want to changing this width property, and have full control about this.
So I readed i can make some custom CSS variable to save my width:

```
:host {
     --my-width: 200px;
}
div{
     width: var(--my-width);
}
```

This is nice because now I have one CSS variable, and I can set this attribute to few selectors, elements.

The question is - how to get this variable in JS and change it in that way **(pseudocode)**:

```
--my-width = --my-width + 10px
```

I know i can use this

```
this.updateStyles({
   '--my-width': '210px'
});
```

to replace value, but I want to code something like this:

```
this.updateStyles({
   '--my-width': '--my-width'.value + 10px
});
```

So that I could changing this width by adding some values (+10px) , not defining new  (= 210px)

I'm asking about how to make this and about some good practices in polymer, how to do that.

Comment: Are you using Polymer 1.x or 2.0?

Comment: @JordanRunning 2.0, but If u know solution for 1.0 please tell me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and [`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue):

```
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(this);
const myWidth = styles.getPropertyValue('--my-width');

const newWidth = `${parseFloat(myWidth) + 10}px`;
this.updateStyles({ '--my-width': newWidth });
```

It's worth reading the [Polymer docs on custom properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-css-properties). Although I'm not sure they're 100% up-to-date, they have some useful information re: Shady DOM.

An alternative, depending on your use case and the browsers you're targeting, is the [CSS `calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
div {
  width: calc(var(--my-width) + 10px);
}
```

You could do the same with `updateStyles`, of course.

Comment: This "first" solution looks good. For now I give You "useful mark", tommorow I will code this and then I will mark as correct answer.
Thank You very much - i think this solution is exactly what i needed.